# Content Type with tabs

Tags: nodes

I am new Drupal user working on a Drupal 7 site. We have a content type that allows us to add related content in tabs that are aligned down the left side of the page. How do I duplicate (clone?) this content type and make slight modifications?

Comment: you can go to admin/structure/types that shows you the list of all content types. You can edit the existing content type or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Bundle Copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module. It'll let you clone a content type.